# RedirectToAction for areas?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have setup some areas, but I'm not sure how to Redirect to them via the RedirectToAction method. There doesn't seem to be any Area parameter I can feed it.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to use [RedirectToRoute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoroute.aspx) if you are trying to redirect to an ActionResult outside the current area.  You will first want to make sure you have a route to the ActionResult you would like to redirect to registered for your area.  The following article is helpful for this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee307987(VS.100).aspx#registering_routes_in_account_and_store_areas

Once you have routes in place, you can do `return RedirectToRoute("MyRouteName");`

Answer (score 6):

This will work too:

```
return RedirectToAction("ActionName","ControllerName", new { area = "AreaName" });
```