# RedirectToAction outside of Areas

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-areas

I've recently updated our MVC 2 project at work to use Areas however I'm having a little problem with the `RedirectToAction` method.

We still have some of our controllers etc outside of our Areas. These controllers include the Home controller etc.

How do I do a `RedirectToAction` from inside an Area to a controller outside of Areas.

I thought something like the following might work but doesn't:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { area = "" });
```

or

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { area = null });
```

Comment: Its mean you want to move to new URL , Outside the controller ? M i getting right?

Comment: I want to redirect to an action which is outside the current Area.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It seems that my origional solution:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { area = "" });
```

does infact work.

I'm not sure how I was managing to make it not work before but it seems to be working as expected now.

Also worth noting that Visual Studio 2010 still tells me that `Cannot resolve action 'Index'` even though the code works fine.

Comment: return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { area = "" });                                
Thanks, it's work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try `return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new {area = Nothing});`

Scrub the above...

Check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846090/redirecttoaction-for-areas) here.  Basically I thought you were trying to do this in a View initially and not a controller action.  Since I see that it is a controller action, you have to use `RedirectToRoute` to change from your current area.

Comment: I think Nothing is a VB.NET thing. I'm using C#. I tried it anyway just to be sure but yeah, it doesn't work.

Comment: Indeed it is, guess that C# tag should have alerted me to a different language :)  anyways, found some additional info for you to check out.

Comment: Thanks for your help Tommy. I did try out the RedirectToRoutes thing after finding it on Google and it does work! I've also discovered that my question is a bit null-and-void since my RedirectToAction code started to work...I must have done something silly to stop it working but i'm unsure what.